# Человек и люди - формы для множественного числа

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные

Как правильно: "написать тридцати людям" или "написать тридцати человекам"?

Comment: Поскольку другим живым существам не пишут никогда, не лучше ли не употреблять понятия "человек, люди"? В вашем контексте уместнее говорить об адресатах.

Answer (score 6):

Если говорящий подрядился разослать "письма счастья" незнакомцам, то для него имеет значение только их количество и он может отчитаться перед нанимателем, что "**написал 30 человекам**" - это единица измерения. Если же он вознамерился привлечь этим внимание к чему-то многих известных ему людей, то он "**написал 30 разным людям**" (слово "разным" здесь полностью сглаживает стилистические шероховатости).

Answer (score 2):

> Как правильно?.. тридцати людям или тридцати человекам?

В сочетаниях со словами, обозначающими количество, в косвенных падежах множественного числа употребляется существительное ***человек***.

Примеры из Розенталя:

***"сорока человекам", "не больше, чем 25 человекам"…***

Answer (score 1):

1) **Почему  некорректно для нашего слуха звучат эти предложения:**

А) Написать тридцати людям

Формы ЛЮДЯМ, ЛЮДЬМИ, О ЛЮДЯХ обычно используются в выражениях «многим людям, всем людям», так как по существу они имеют семантику собирательности, а не  единичного счета. Поэтому для больших чисел ею пользоваться неудобно.

Б) Написать тридцати человекам

Форма мн. числа ЧЕЛОВЕКАМ, которая раньше применялась  свободно, в настоящее время устаревает. В современным словарях она разрешена  только в сочетаниях с числительными.

Таким образом, на формы мн. числа ЧЕЛОВЕКАМ, ЧЕЛОВЕКАХ, ЧЕЛОВЕКАМИ уже оказывается давление, и они становятся непривычными для слуха, хотя еще допускается их применение.

Обычно мы широко пользуемся только двумя формами -  ЧЕЛОВЕК, ЧЕЛОВЕКА, например: тридцать человек, не хватает тридцати человек.

2) Вывод: Если речь идет о больших числах, то желательна замена форм ЛЮДЯМ, ЧЕЛОВЕКАМ на другие существительные, обозначающих людей в конкретной ситуации.